# How to fix error 'no suitable method found' in AndroidStudio?

Tags: android

I have been developing some code in `AndroidStudio`, when the error occurred. Then I removed the last bit of code I have changed, but the error was still there! Even after a `Clean Project` the project does not build again!

I am using the library `compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.1'` in `dependencies` in the file `build.gradle`, and here is the foll code I am using:

`activity_main.xml`:

```
    <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/graph" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

`MainActivity.class`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(graph);
    }
}
```

And here is the full error message, which does not make any sense:

```
Error:(23, 39) error: no suitable method found for findViewById(GraphView)
method Activity.findViewById(int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; GraphView cannot be converted to int)
method AppCompatActivity.findViewById(int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; GraphView cannot be converted to int)
```

I bet you will not get that error, but I do. The code worked like it is, but suddenly this error occurrs. Maybe I need to restart `AndroidStudio`? Or is there another `Clean` command?

Comment: Yes, great. But I never changed that!

Comment: So, how is this possible then? I inserted some code at the very bottom of the code. How can this change something in a different part of the code?

Comment: I copied the example from a site in the internet! I NEVER typed in the wrong line without the `R.id`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130834/discussion-between-alex-and-mike-m).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
```

instead of

```
GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(graph);
```

Answer (score 3):

in this line

```
 GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(graph);
```

you are providing the `graph` object you just declared as argument to `findViewById` and, of course, the compiler is complaining about the non-existences of an overloaded method `findViewById` which takes as parameter a `GraphView`.

The argument of `findViewById` is an `int`, the id of view you declared in your layout, and listed under `R.id`. Like in

```
  GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
```